# Extract specific pages from a PDF file and save it with a specific name given on a excel using VBA or Python or VBA & Python

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-extraction

Let me mention below the steps and constrains.

1. I am using PDF Xchange editor
2. There is an excel document with PDF location (cell A1), PDF file name (cell A2), page range to extract/split which has start page (A3) and end page (A4) and finally that specific extraction name that need to be saved as (A5) and sved location (A6). (There are multiple items, ie cells B#s C#s D#s etc.)
3. Based on the data on excel I need to create a tool using VBA or Python or both.

Thanks in advance

Try to create a tool onlyvwith VBA but failed on point acrobat.exch.

Im expecting tool to create new extractions using an excel as input file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible using VBA to first convert the PDF to a Word document. Then you would be able to manipulate the document as necessary with VBA before saving again as a new PDF to final folder location.